# Fork, Clone, Checkout a Branch, Then Push Back to Same Branch

Tags: git, github

I keep running into the same issue where I can't push back to the same branch that I checkout. The repo that I am working on is Angular University, Angular Material. I wanted to be able to work across my machine from home and work. The idea was to Fork the repo, clone it to both machines, then checkout the branch I wanted to work on (it would be the same), then push back to the same branch in the forked repo, then I could update the other machine at work/home.  I either end up with a detached head or with a message stating that I am not working in the branch.

**Steps to reproduce:**

```bash
# Fork the repository: https://github.com/angular-university/angular-material-course.git

# Clone the repository on my local machine
git clone https://github.com/<myusername>/<forked repository name>

# Checkout the branch that I want
git branch -a

# See the list
git checkout -b branchname

# Make modifications
git push origin localbranch:remotebranch
```

Is there something obviously wrong with the strategy that I am attempting or the commands that I am using?

Comment: `git checkout -b branchname` is not right in your case. It's equivalent to `git checkout -b branchname HEAD` but I think you need `git checkout -b branchname remotes/origin/branchname`, or simply `git checkout branchname` when there exists `remotes/origin/branchname` and `branchname` doesn't exist yet. Detached head is usually caused by checking out a literal hash or a tag.

Comment: I would really like to mark Omar's answer as the solution as he was 100% correct. The problem was the difference between the two argument and one argument form of the git checkout -b command. The one argument form creates a local branch suitable for creating a new branch with working changes in the remote. The two argument form creates a local branch with tracking to an upstream repository as specified in the second argument.